# how to store large dictionary in swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a dictionary of key:value pairs that i am using for a collection view, each button.tag triggers a key that loads an array of numbers for the collection, everything works fine up until around tile number 106. After which i get an "Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4" error which i can't make head nor tails of.

maybe it is to do with how the tiles are stored? at the moment i have it stored in a swift file that looks like this:

```
import Foundation

    let tiles = [0:[0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160],
    1:[0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160],
    2:[0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160],
    3:[0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160],
    4:[0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160],
    5:[0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160],
...
```

all the way to 175. it works as normal up to around 106, after that i get the error. It is a swift compiler error - I am pretty sure i am storing my key:value pairs badly too so any advice is welcome! thanks for your time

Comment: Im solved! do i leave this up or is it fraff?

Comment: `let tiles: [Int: [Int]] = [0: ...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a single large dictionary literal, break the construction of the dictionary into multiple statements.

```
var tiles = [0:[0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160]]
tiles[1] = [0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160]
// and so on
```

Comment: you are a dream

Answer (score 1):

If the array is the same you can try

```
var tiles = [Int:[Int]]()

(0...175).forEach {

    tiles[$0] = [0,11,52,35,54,55,64,70,80,67,54,60,73,162,171,160]

}

print(tiles)
```